# I am getting CSS SyntaxError, unexpected token {. But I can not see error

Tags: wordpress, css, localhost, laragon

In Wordpress on localhost Laragon I am trying to get CSS. It throws 403 error: 
[image]

[image]

I can't find error, what could it be?

Comment: Your CSS file is being processed as JavaScript. For obvious reasons, this won't work.

Comment: try to remove the comment of the CSS file

Comment: check your css i think some of the css class is not closed ( } ).

Comment: @geeksamu Why? `/* comments */` are a perfectly valid part of CSS and should even be considered mandatory.

Comment: @VikasJadhav I don't even know where to *start* with that one. The error is occurring before any possible place where a `}` would "fix" it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol validate your css here http://csslint.net/ it will show you all the erros in your css.

Comment: How is the CSS being linked in the HTML? It appears that it is being linked as JavaScript.

Comment: @VikasJadhav Yup. No errors in the code shown, especially not at `body {`. Funny that.

Comment: show us how you are include the CSS file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably using `wp_enqueue_script()` Wordpress function to include your stylesheet file, and that's what could cause the error because it will call the css file using script tag.

Try using `wp_enqueue_style()` function instead.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you :)

Comment: thanks ! I had the same error while adding bundles in MVC with scriptBundle instead of StyleBundle.

Answer (score 22):

You css file is being processed as a javascript file. 
Are you sure the file is being included as a css file as in

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and not

```
<script src="style.css"></script>
```

Also if you are adding this in code make sure you are using the `wp_enqueue_style()` method